# How to extend array structure in nested loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with products, filled by the API.

I want to extend it and add some values like `categories`, `price`. I tried to add `&` before the array when looping to use it by reference row. But when I added another `while` loop to add `categories`, the `$row` wasn't extended.

```
$products = array('id_product'=>12,'link'=>'test.html','description'=>'desc'); 
foreach($products as &$row) { 
    $row['price'] = 12;
    $product = new Product($row['id_product'];
    $categories = $product::getCategories();
    $k = 1; 
    while ($cat = current($categories)){
        $row['categoryid'.$k] = $cat['name'];
        $k++; 
    }
}
```

`$product::getCategories()` return

> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(8) "T-shirts" } }

The problem is that the array key with `categoryid.$k` is never created, I tried with `foreach` on categories but it didn't work.

Comment: what is returning `$product::getCategories();` ?

Comment: @MateiMihai i edited my question with the categories

Answer (score 0):

In provided example in foreach loop $row will contains values 12, 'test.html' and 'desc'. So you can't use them as array.
Valid code:

```
$products = array();
$products[] = array('id_product'=>12,'link'=>'test.html','description'=>'desc');
```

Also you have invalid while loop, replace **current** function with **array_shift**, or use proper foreach loop

**Edited**:
Replace while with this code:

```
if (!empty($categories)) {
    foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
      $row['categoryid' . $key] = $category['name'];
    }
  }
```

Comment: may real code is too long, that's why i gived a resumed one, my real problem is with $row['categoryid'.$k] that is not added, $prodcuts is given with an sql query

Comment: i can't use array_shift since i need the array to use it later

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by adding a function and pass by value the row parameter

```
private function addCategories(&$row){
     $categories = $this->getProductCategoriesFull((int)$row['id_product']);

            if (!empty($categories)) {
                $k = 2;

                foreach($categories as $category) {
                  if($k!= 2)
                  $row['categoryid' . ($k-1)] = $category['name'];

                  $k++;
                  if($k>5) exit;
                }
            }

}
```

And call it in the loop

```
$this->addCategories($row);
```